# How to send canvas image to server react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, react-redux

How send canvas to server?

I'm using react-cropper

Output is base64 but i need send it like form data with `fetch`

Is it possible to do like that?

```
static upload(files) {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append(files[0].name, files[0]);
    const request = new Request("/api/upload-photo", {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',

        body: JSON.stringify(files)
    });

    return fetch(request).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
}
```

Comment: Send the canvas's data to the server, such as making it an image and converting it to base64 data.

Comment: This is not related to react/redux. it is ore how to send date using ajax